# Master-master replication and Master-snapshot replication

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle10g

I want to know what  Master-master replication and Master-snapshot replication are.
what they do, how they are used and their importance.

Comment: Why is this tagged `MySQL` and `Oracle`?  Which database are you really using?

Comment: I am using  oracle, don't know why I tagged MySQL